# PHP page to download MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to import excel data into datatables? My requirement here is, I want to export datatables data into xls/csv, make bulk changes and import it back to datatables (mysql backend). Is there any plugin for this import?? Please advise. Thanks in advance.

I want to do this import and export on my php webpage, not from mysql directly. Basically, I want to give users an option to bulk download and upload of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export to CSV:

```
SELECT *
INTO OUTFILE 'filename.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM tablename
```

You can import from CSV:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL 
INFILE 'filaneme.csv' INTO TABLE tablename
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(col1, col2, col3,...)
```

**UPDATED**
Here's the general idea - write a header, loop through rows, return it with a text/csv MIME-TYPE

```
$rsResults = mysql_query($sql, $db) or die(mysql_error());
$out = '';

$fields = mysql_list_fields('database','table',$db);
$columns = mysql_num_fields($fields);

for ($i = 0; $i < $columns; $i++) {
    $l=mysql_field_name($fields, $i);
    $out .= '"'.$l.'",';
}

$out .="\n";

while ($l = mysql_fetch_array($rsResults)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $columns; $i++) {
        $out .='"'.$l["$i"].'",';
    }
    $out .="\n";
}

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=table.csv");
header("Content-type: text/csv");

echo $out;

exit;
```

Comment: I want to do this import and export on my php webpage, not from mysql directly. Basically, I want to give users an option to bulk download and upload of data

Comment: Still working on it. Your expanded post, is it necessary for export? The SELECT query for export worked in phpadmin atleast, without headers though. There should be some option to extract the headers as well.

Comment: My php code will grab a table and rip out all of the data into a block of text - the `header` directives tell the browser to treat it as if the user had downloaded a csv file called table.csv it's a generic way of grabbing all the information in a table and should work on your site.

Comment: The solution is pitched at letting end users grab their own data, I really don't have the resources to do the whole thing, I can just give you pointers.

Comment: Hi, the SELECT and LOAD statements are working on my local machine (MAMP). But will they work on client-server environment? In production, I'll have my app running on LAMP. I read somewhere that SELECT.. INTO OUTFILE doesn't work on client file system.

Comment: I now have trouble uploading the data to php/mysql. I have one main_page.php. The upload form in on this main_page.php and upload code is on upload.php. The upload code runs perfectly, but the page wouldn't return to main_page.php. The control is staying on upload.php which is empty since the upload is successful. Now how do I return to main_page.php without any user action?